# Configuring a password policy on Cisco IOS or NX-OS

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, security, cisco-nexus-5k, cisco-nexus-7k

I was wondering if it's possible at all to configure a password policy which enforces password complexity for locally defined accounts. I know it's possible for TACACS+ and RADIUS, but I need to know if it's possible to enforce such policy for locally defined accounts.

The devices I have in scope are running IOS and NX-OS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding password complexity for local accounts, you have these options...

- **Cisco NX-OS**: I'm not sure you can configure a local password policy in NX-OS; however, NX-OS [rejects weak passwords by default](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5000/sw/configuration/guide/cli/CLIConfigurationGuide/sec_rbac.html#wp1258879).  To disable this feature, use `no password strength-checking` in the global configuration.
- **Cisco IOS**:

  - Password length: [`security password min-length`](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/security/s1/sec-s1-cr-book/sec-cr-s1.html#wp4245155510).  Admittedly, length is a fairly weak check itself, but IOS at least can detect / deny brute force attacks (see below).

There are a few things to remember...

- Many older versions of Cisco IOS use a [weak "Type 7" hash](http://packetlife.net/toolbox/type7/) to protect passwords from shoulder-surfing; there are a billion tools like this on the internet to reverse those hashes.  Type 7 hashes should not be considered secure and thus, archive configs in a directory with good permissions enforcement (i.e. your linux tftp directory probably isn't a good location, since most people change tftp file permissions to 777).

  - Ironically the weak "Type 7" algorithm looks secure to the uninitiated, and is enabled with a command called `service password-encryption`.
  - One should always use the `secret` keyword when possible in usernames: i.e. `username joe secret 5 $1$pJz5$28CTViXggZmhjikYdDyls0`.   This is at least a decent `md5` hash of the plaintext password.  Newer IOS versions [attempt to use a stronger algorithm](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2613969/password-security/cisco-inadvertently-weakens-password-encryption-in-its-ios-operating-system.html), but failed before getting it right.
  - It's not a bad idea to audit local accounts to see whether you can upgrade them to use the `secret` keyword. In linux, it's as simple as `grep ^username /path/to/your/configs/* | grep -v secret` (making a note to myself to do this today at my $dayjob)
- Newer versions of IOS have a feature to trap brute-force attacks against the router; an ACL is applied to the vty.

  - This command would automatically apply an acl to block the offending source IP address for 60 seconds if it had failed password checks 3 times in five minutes: `login block-for 60 attempts 3 within 300`
  - You can customize the access-list which is applied using `login quiet-mode access-class [acl-name]`; by default [IOS applies an acl called `sl_def_acl`](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6675/775)